# Start a new contribution on github using Git

Tags: git, github

I was working on keras project on Github using git. I have finished my contribution and now i want to start a new contribution process on Pandas. Note that I have deleted the previous keras folders from my local repo.

I have followed the contribution guidelines for Pandas (forking, cloning the repo etc).
My question is how can i start a fresh master branch? Because now I think I have messed up my branches with Keras.  When I write git status it shows a bunch of deleted files for keras ans some Untracked files: (images bellow)
[image: Untracked files]
[image: deleted files]

Also when I write git branch I see one master branch. Is this master referring to pandas?
[image]

Comment: You've created a repository in your home directory. DON'T DO THAT!

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have make a new folder on my desktop and cloned it there. But nothing changed on branches names. The pandas 'main' branch is not showing when I write git branch . Only the 'master' one which I think is from my previous work